# How to get average distance between 3 points

Tags: c, math, logic

I found a programming question to calculate average distance between 3 known points.

You have given three coordinates points (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and (x3,y3) and I have to calculate average distance among these points.

If any body knows formula please let me know I can write in coding.

My approach:- 
I can get distance between each coordinate from the distance formula but how will I calculate average distance, don't know.

distance1  =  point between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)

distance2 = point between (x1,y1) and (x3,y3)

distnace3  = point between (x2,y2) and (x3,y3)

Reference from

http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/trigonometry/triangle_given_3_points.htm

Comment: What is average distance? An average of three distances? Don't you know how to calculate an average of three numbers?

Comment: `(distance1 + distance2 + distance3) / 3` , assuming the distances are not weighted?

Comment: Is it correct??? I know and I have done it by this same approach but not sure if it is triangle.
To get average distance I can calculate it be (D1+D2+D3)/3.

Comment: It is curious that OP "can get distance between each coordinate from the distance formula" yet has trouble with "calculate average distance".

Comment: Ajay_Kumar, Anything more needed here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using C, the distance between 2 points is simply

```
#include <math.h>
double x1, y1;
double x2, y2;
double distance1 = hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);
```

The average distance of the 3 sides of the triangle (given 3 known points) would be

```
double distance_avg = (distance1 + distance2 + distance3)/3;
```

Answer (score -1):

The Average distance between 3 points in a Triangle basically means that you need to find out the Centroid of that particular Triangle.

So, given 3 points, you have 3 x-coordinates and 3 y-coordinates.

So just take the Average of the X and Y co-ordinates and you'll be done.
Something like:

`xmean = (x1+x2+x3)/3`

and

`ymean = (y1+y2+y3)/3`

More information on : http://www.mathopenref.com/coordcentroid.html

Comment: You are calculating here the average of three points rather than distances. Not sure what the OP wants, though..